# Локализация надписи на самой важной кнопке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На сайте есть надписи на кнопках:

1. **Задать** вопрос
2. **Отправить** вопрос
3. **Отправьте** ваш ответ
4. **Добавить** ещё один ответ
5. **Сохранить** изменения

Найдите пятую лишнюю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в «*Отправьте* ваш ответ». Изменил на «*Отправить* ответ».

Изменения будут доступны в следующей сборке.

Comment: Из ответа не ясно что же именно было сделано. Будьте добры поподробнее.

Comment: @alexolut Обновил ответ.

Comment: В других строках YOUR не переведено. В принципе из контекста и так понятно, что каждый отправляет свой собственный вопрос или ответ.

Comment: @alexolut Да, мне тоже так кажется. Обновил перевод.

Comment: А может это такое уведомление, что плагиатить не надо? :)

Comment: @alexolut: Насколько я понимаю, это стандартная форма в английском языке. В русском обычно вместо этого используется форма «свой ответ» или вообще ничего. «Отправьте ваш ответ» — явная калька с английского.